mysql: Food processing ordering in different "Food Category" and different "Food Processing Type"
I want to sort below input to get output so that for everyday, customer have different "Food Category" (priority first) and then different "Food Processing Type" (as much different as possible) to eat.
Input:



Food Category
Food Processing Type
Food Name




beef
braised
beef-braised1


beef
braised
beef-braised2


beef
stir-fry
beef-stir-fry3


beef
stir-fry
beef-stir-fry4


beef
boiled
beef-boiled5


beef
boiled
beef-boiled6


fish
braised
fish-braised1


fish
braised
fish-braised2


fish
stir-fry
fish-stir-fry3


fish
stir-fry
fish-stir-fry4


fish
boiled
fish-boiled5


fish
boiled
fish-boiled6



I tried to do it with php and can get below result.
My question is: Can we do it by query in mysql
Expected result:



Food Category
Food Processing Type
Food Name




beef
braised
beef-braised1


fish
stir-fry
fish-stir-fry3


beef
boiled
beef-boiled5


fish
braised
fish-braised1


beef
stir-fry
beef-stir-fry3


fish
boiled
fish-boiled5


beef
braised
beef-braised2


fish
stir-fry
fish-stir-fry4


beef
boiled
beef-boiled6


fish
braised
fish-braised2


beef
stir-fry
beef-stir-fry4


fish
boiled
fish-boiled6



Thank you and Best Regards,
